Evaluate $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}2^{\frac{1}{a_k}}\right)$
Evaluate the following limit, where $(a_n)_{n≥1}$ is the prime numbers sequence
$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}2^{\frac{1}{a_k}}\right)$
A friend suggested and asked me this problem and I don't have any clue how to approach it.

This does not seem to converge, since it is a series and the general term does not go to zero

The terms do not converge to $0.$

You might be able to find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}...,$$ essentially the even subsequence of the original partial sum.

But I doubt there is a closed for for that - there really is no reason to expect one.

I rejected the edit which attempted to replace $\lim_n\sum_{k=1}^n$ with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ because it removes one of the ways to fix the question.
